# Way to enable & disable the Camel XML Routes with some property

Tags: java, xml, apache, apache-camel

Actually I want to enable or disable the camel XML routes. I tried with the autoStartup but it was not working as I have a route with paho and it's failing because of no connection.

I want to disable the routes, where I don't have the connection available.

Thanks in advance.